# How to get data from sd-bus container using c++

Tags: c++, linux, systemd, dbus

When using `GetAll` method in DBus.properties, the result is

```
   array [
  dict entry(
     string "Id"
     variant             string "cockpit.service"
  )
  dict entry(
     string "Names"
     variant             array [
           string "cockpit.service"
        ]
  )
  dict entry(
     string "Following"
     variant             string ""
  )
  dict entry(
     string "Requires"
     variant             array [
           string "sysinit.target"
           string "system.slice"
           string "cockpit-wsinstance-http.socket"
           string "cockpit-wsinstance-https-factory.socket"
           string "cockpit-wsinstance-http-redirect.socket"
           string "-.mount"
           string "cockpit.socket"
        ]
  )
.... ]
```

So, I entered first array container using `sd_bus_message_enter_container(reply,'a',"{sv}")` And entered second sv container using `(reply,'e',"sv")`. Then, I want read data from this container but their data types are different. So i can't read data like , `read(reply,"s",&data)` `(const char * data)` because it can be string, array, array of bytes .... So, how do i get this data?

Correct way to get data from container

Answer (score 0):

Recent systemd versions have the `sd_bus_message_peek_type()` function to determine the type of the next value. (Note that GetAll property values are always of 'variant' type; it's the value *inside* the variant that you want.)

Generally, a given property will always be of the same type. For example, if you know that you've just read the key name `Id`, then you'll be expecting a string value every time.